# Duvida da aplicação Server JAVA e TomCat

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

Galera, to precisando de uma ajuda. Tenho uma aplicação server em JAVA EE e preciso usando TomCat subir essa aplicação para usa-lá em outra aplicação. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não é necessário adicionar [resolvido] no titulo. Só de ter aceito a resposta clicando no `v` verde, já demonstra que você encontrou a solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve gerar o .war dessa apliicação que você possui. Pelo eclipse no menu Export... você consegue encontrar a opção "war file", dai no tomcat você acessa o managment via web e fazer o deploy do app. Abaixo um video do youtube explicando como fazer utilizando a web do tomcat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X9DA8oVodk